# Meaning of new statistic in dotTrace hotspots

Tags: .net, profiling, dottrace

There is a new statistic in the hotspots line for dotTrace. Instead of listing just the total "own time" of a function such as

175,708 ms,

one now sees something like

175,708/1200 ms.

That is, in the new version it gives two numbers, the first of which looks like the total own time, but then there is a slash and a second number. This second number does not show up in either the help that comes with the current version of dotTrace or their online help.

Can someone give an authoritative interpretation of the second number. Is it some measure of the variation in the call times (that would be great), or something else?

Can anyone give or refer me to a definitive answer?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Studying_Profiling_Results__Hot_Spots.html) that metric is:

> Own time including time spent in system functions / Own time only.

In your example: 175,708ms was spent by that method AND all system functions it called, and 1,200ms of that was just in the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the results are grouped by 'Own+System Time' in the 'Hot Spots' view. If so, then the first number is the sum of the system and the own time of the function, the second number is function's own time.